# How can I draw a selection rectangle on the screen with Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11

How can I draw a selection rectangle on my screen with Qt in X11?
I want to be able to drag a rectangle on my screen (outside of the application) and then save the whole rectangle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the solution will involve using the `grabWindow()` function of `QPixmap` like so:

```
QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());
```

Qt has an [example program for this here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/desktop-screenshot.html).

There rest of the solution, drawing the area to grab, can probably be achieved by either using a full screen transparent window to render a mouse drawn rectangle and then taking the section it outlines from the grabbed desktop image or using a full screen window with the entire grabbed screen painted on it.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I know. This was my initial approach. Since I'm writing a screenshot utility, do you think the time it will take for it to initialize itself and take a full-sized screenshot is gonna be noticeable?

Comment: I would imagine it to be as responsive as any other screenshot utility. Building and testing the example program would be a quick experiment.

Comment: Myeah, okay, I'm just gonna go with your answer. Thanks.